# Nagios: Specify a contact group for a whole host group?

Tags: nagios

I'm migrating a config from a very old version of Nagios (1.5 something I think) to Nagios 3.5.1.

The config I'm moving has contact groups specified for the host groups.

The new Nagios says `Error: Invalid hostgroup object directive 'contact_groups'.`

What's the right way to set the groups to be contacted for a hostgroup in the new Nagios? Or are we supposed to set the contact groups for each host manually (which would be quite the process?) Can anyone point me to any release notes or documentation about this change?

(I've looked for release notes mentioning this and for documentation explaining the right way to do this, but so far have had no luck).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per this [ChangeLog](http://sourceforge.net/p/nagios/svn/HEAD/tree/nagioscore/branches/nagios-2-x-bugfixes/Changelog) :

> The contact groups directive has moved from hostgroup definitions to
>   host definitions

since version `2.0b1` released on December 15 2004.

---

From now, `contact_groups` can only be applied to hosts.

By the way, from [Nagios support Forum](http://support.nagios.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=21459) :

> The proper way to do this is to use host templates. You can then add
>   the contacts and hostgroups you want to the template, and then apply
>   the template to the hosts.